# Target WSGI script myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtual

I a trying to run a "hello world" python application from the server using Apache web server port 80. Here, I have setup python virtual environment compacting with python version 3.8. created virtual host, wsgi file and now trying to call the URL on browser, I am getting 500 internal server error. Apache error log file details provided here.

```
1. Ubuntu 18.04,
2. Python 3.8,
3. Apache 2.4
```

```
 Virtual host configuration

    #WSGIDaemonProcess MyApp python-home=/usr/local/env/myApp/venv threads=5i
WSGIDaemonProcess Myapp user=www-data group=www-data python-home=/usr/local/env/myApp/venv  python-path=/usr/local/env/myApp threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /project_wsgi /usr/local/env/myApp/myapp.wsgi
#WSGIProcessGroup myApp
WSGIApplicationGroup Myapp
#WSGIImportScript  %{GLOBAL}
#WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/env/myApp/venv

<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /usr/local/env/myApp>
         Require all granted
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
LogLevel info
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

```
WSGI file

import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/local/env/myApp/')

python_home = '/usr/local/env/myApp/venv'
#activate_this = '/usr/local/env/myApp/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
#with open(activate_this) as file_:
#    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

from app.myApp import app as application
```

```
apache error logs
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:28.990978 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 58589:tid 140712013437888] mod_wsgi (pid=58589): Starting process 'Myapp' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=5.
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:28.991819 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 58589:tid 140712013437888] mod_wsgi (pid=58589): Python home /usr/local/env/myApp/venv.
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:28.991863 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 58589:tid 140712013437888] mod_wsgi (pid=58589): Initializing Python.
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:28.991926 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 102854:tid 140712013437888] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:28.991937 2020] [mpm_event:info] [pid 102854:tid 140712013437888] AH00490: Server built: 2019-09-16T12:58:48
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:28.991952 2020] [core:notice] [pid 102854:tid 140712013437888] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:28.993170 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 58591:tid 140712013437888] mod_wsgi (pid=58591): Initializing Python.
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:28.993874 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 58590:tid 140712013437888] mod_wsgi (pid=58590): Initializing Python.
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:29.061111 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 58589:tid 140712013437888] mod_wsgi (pid=58589): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:29.088271 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 58589:tid 140712013437888] mod_wsgi (pid=58589): Adding '/usr/local/env/myApp' to path.
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:29.089075 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 58591:tid 140712013437888] mod_wsgi (pid=58591): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Jan 31 16:00:29.089966 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 58590:tid 140712013437888] mod_wsgi (pid=58590): Attach interpreter ''.
```

```
[Fri Jan 31 16:02:22.375687 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 58591:tid 140711785658112] [client 146.176.178.57:50395] mod_wsgi (pid=58591, process='', application='Myapp'): Loading WSGI script '/usr/local/env/myApp/myapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Jan 31 16:02:22.381101 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 58591:tid 140711785658112] [client 146.176.178.57:50395] mod_wsgi (pid=58591): Target WSGI script '/usr/local/env/myApp/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Jan 31 16:02:22.381132 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 58591:tid 140711785658112] [client 146.176.178.57:50395] mod_wsgi (pid=58591): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/env/myApp/myapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Jan 31 16:02:22.381374 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 58591:tid 140711785658112] [client 146.176.178.57:50395] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jan 31 16:02:22.381400 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 58591:tid 140711785658112] [client 146.176.178.57:50395]   File "/usr/local/env/myApp/myapp.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
[Fri Jan 31 16:02:22.381405 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 58591:tid 140711785658112] [client 146.176.178.57:50395]     from app.myApp import app as application
[Fri Jan 31 16:02:22.381411 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 58591:tid 140711785658112] [client 146.176.178.57:50395]   File "/usr/local/env/myApp/app/myApp.py", line 1, in <module>
[Fri Jan 31 16:02:22.381414 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 58591:tid 140711785658112] [client 146.176.178.57:50395]     from flask import Flask
[Fri Jan 31 16:02:22.381436 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 58591:tid 140711785658112] [client 146.176.178.57:50395] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

I have installed flask on the virtual environment and trying to activate from the WSGI file execution. However, this is not working for me.

FYI : The commented lines on virtual host is already I have tried.

Comment: Appreciate the FYI at the end, but I'd just add that info to the commented code block so we find it out when reading the code and not after we get to the end of the code :). Otherwise well-written. +1.

Comment: Can you do a `pip list` and verify that flask is in the results? Also, how are you running the app?